# Does the quartz crystal in the standard clock vibrate the same frequency as the sweep motion one?

Tags: digital-logic, crystal, counter

In the standard quartz clocks/watches,the quartz crystal vibrates 32768 times
per seconds(32768HZ),while this frequency is divided by an electronic counter(15 bit binary digital counter)to derive one second pulse,which drives a step-motor.
Most of the quartz clocks have a second hand which ticks once per seconds,due to the explain above,but there are,also,quartz clocks which their second hand ticks several times per seconds and they called"quartz sweep clock movements".
Do on those quartz sweep clocks,the quartz crystal vibrates at the same frequency(32768 HZ)as the standard ones?while the counter is,actually,just divided the  32768 frequency to a request frequency value?I mean,if the second hand ticks 4 time per second,Does it,actually,use a 13 bit binary digital counter,which produced 4Hz?

Thanks

Comment: This Seiko service manual (https://service.seiko.com.au/i/seiko/documents/technicalguides/5S21A.pdf) indicates that a stepper motor at 4 Hz is used.

Comment: Yes,i see that.But it didn't mention what is the frequency that the quartz crystal of this quartz sweep clock vibrates and this is my main question.

Comment: Bulova UHF. uses 262kHz

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too broad because there are multiple technically valid possibilities.  The question fails to state a given model so it cannot be specifically answered, and if it did state a given model it would be an off-topic question about a particular consumer product rather than a *design* question.

Answer (score 2):

32768 Hz crystals are readily available. If you want a 131072 Hz crystal, many crystal manufacturers will be happy to sell you a tailor made one, but at a price. A different divider ratio will cost you nothing.

Comment: I understand that 131072 Hz crystal with 15 bit binary digital counter will divide the frequency to 4HZ,but what i am trying to understand is if the quarts sweep clocks are using the same crystal quartz frequency(32768HZ)as the standard quartz clocks?

Comment: Yeah, most likely. The reason why 32768Hz is used is battery life. The higher the frequency of the crystal, the more often the CMOS circuitry of the divider switches.